# GitLab CE API: Check if used token has admin rights

Tags: python, python-3.x, gitlab, gitlab-api

I am working on a Python module for the [GitLab API](http://doc.gitlab.com/ce/api/README.html). Is there any possibility to check if the user with the `private token` in use has admin rights on the GitLab server?

One way would be to get something from the API, e.g. a single user and check, if it has the elements [only the admin can see](http://doc.gitlab.com/ce/api/users.html#for-admins) like `two_factor_enabled`. But is there a better, easier way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [api help](https://gitlab.com/help/api/users.md#single-user) the `is_admin` key is now included for all single user api queries.

I just tested it with the api v4 on gitlab.com with the query:

`curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: Token" https://gitlab.com/api/v4/users/###`

and the json answer included `"is_admin":false` for the specified user with the id `###`.

Comment: doesn't work for me...

Comment: The question is about a _given private-token_ - not about a _given user-id._ The solution here works only if you know the user-id and you are using a token with admin-rights.

Answer (score 1):

Can run a query that works just for admins, for example:

`curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: Token" https://my.gitlab.host/api/v4/users?admins=true`

Because `admins=true` works only for users with admin-rights, if you get any reply it means that token has admin-rights.

(from: [GitLab Docs: Users API - For Administrators](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/users.html#for-administrators))

Answer (score 0):

If you `GET /users` and pass the `sudo` parameter you will get a JSON back that includes an `is_admin` attribute with a boolean value. You could use that [Here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/users.html#for-admins) is the documentation

Comment: `sudo` is only working as admin, but the `is_admin` key is now included for all user api queries according to https://gitlab.com/help/api/users.md#single-user